# Serial downvoting and downvoting etiquette in general...

Tags: discussion, faq, down-votes, etiquette

I just logged-in and noticed that every single of my contributions (questions and answers) to date had been downvoted: obviously by the same user, most likely without even a reading (there are 10 downvotes over a timespan of a 1-2 minutes: way too short to read everything).

While I would certainly understand my entries being downvoted (like anyone else, I make mistakes), this seems more like some strange power-trip/personal-vendetta by some brave anonymous user who clearly doesn't understand the way SE is supposed to work. When downvoting an accepted answer, a comment, if anything, would seem like the most basic courtesy to both me and other users who might read this answer later.

I really could not care less about the loss to my "reputation points", but I feel this type of childish behaviour, if unchecked, could be very detrimental to both the quality and the atmosphere of the site...

It seems like most other meta sites have had [similar discussions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/687/vindictive-downvoting) before, so I figured this might be the occasion to have our own here:

1. Should we add a FAQ item strongly recommending posting an explanatory comment (with corrections if applicable) when downvoting a consequent entry?
2. Do jp.SE admins have any tools to manually check on this? and if so, would they mind sending a notice to the incriminated user enjoining him not to engage in that sort of behaviour? (it is my understanding that SE has a system in place to reverse serial-downvoting automatically every couple hours, but it would still be helpful to address the root cause).

Any other thought on that?

Comment: Since he does not have any contact info on his profile and this is the only way to send him a note: @Rolf: please read the above and, in the future, refrain from this type of behaviour. Whatever your problem is, it is pretty clear it has nothing to do with the content of my entries. If you see anything questionable in my answers, use comments (and feel free to downvote after that). Furthermore, I believe systematically downvoting other answers in a question you are also replying to is generally frowned upon (not to mention against the spirit of SE). Please post any reply here...

Comment: @Dave, "@someone" will only reach if he commented here.

Comment: @YOU: ah... thanks for the precision... So my only way to contact Rolf is to hunt down an unrelated entry he has commented on and post a note there?

Comment: OK... All the downvotes from yesterday were indeed reversed overnight. **But** a few hours ago, the same thing happened all over again (and it appears to be @Rolf again). I don't know what his problem is (he hasn't bothered replying to any of the messages I left him), but would an admin mind looking into this? This is becoming old now. @YOU, am I right to assume you are one of the *pro tempore* moderators? are there others?

Comment: @Dave, I am not the moderator (moderators and devs are with "diamond" ♦ after the usernames), but that's just obvious for me, since we have very small amount of users here. If he consistently doing that, you may ask for more help on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) site.

Comment: @Dave how did you know is him? i had this problem on my stackoverflow account too and i can't have any prove against that person

Comment: I'm being hit by serial downvotes too. 10 minutes ago (about 1525Hrs GMT+0) Four of my questions got downvoted in a span of 1 minute.

Comment: @Flaw: most likely, this will be caught by the fraud detection system and reverted within 24h. So just sit tight and don't worry about it in the meantime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As YOU said, the system has some mechanism which detects unusual patterns in voting and cancels the suspicious votes.  The process is automatic and runs once a day.

However, some people are childish, and ultimately we cannot change that fact.  We have to live with childish behaviors of some people, and that’s life.  Hopefully that’s only a tiny, tiny part of life.

I am not strongly against recommending explanations for down-voting in FAQ, but note that when you down-vote a post, the system already shows a message which recommends an explanation in comments.  Therefore, I doubt that adding something to FAQ is effective.

Comment: ha! I wasn't aware of the downvote warning (that tells you how much I use it myself... not that I'm fundamentally against it, but I have so far always preferred to use a comment and/or edit suggestion than a downvote ;-) Thanks for the precision, and in this case I agree that a FAQ modification is redundant.

Comment: Redundant != unnecessary or ineffective, though.

Answer (score 4):

SE Engine has vote fraud prevention algorithm, it will reset the votes overnight. Please check it tommorow.

Comment: yes, as I said above, I have read about this system and wasn't really worried about those reputation points to begin with. But I think it is still a problem if the users that behave in such an antisocial way do not get caught early and told to behave... Anyway, I'll have a word with Rolf and hopefully this can be worked out...

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat off-topic, but the closest thing I could find to a relevant question:

I've noticed some people are freaking out over downvotes on meta.  Downvotes (and upvotes even) are different on these SE Meta sites (note that [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is the exception, not the rule).  Voting here does not affect your reputation in any way, your reputation is purely dictated by the amount you have on the main site.  This is because votes on meta are supposed to indicate agreement (with an upvote) or disagreement (with a downvote).

So, feel free to vote up or down to your heart's content without worry that you'll permanently corrupt someone's reputation by saying "I don't agree with this suggestion."  You won't even lose 1 rep for voting down on an answer.

The [Meta FAQ](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) was recently updated to explain this as well.

Comment: Good precision to make, thanks @Troyen!