# Can I reasonably assume that this is retaliatory downvoting?

Tags: discussion, support, etiquette, down-votes

Today, I got [3 downvotes](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/1575/phoenixheart6?tab=reputation)--two were within a minute of one another and the other was 3 minutes later. At the same time, my profile views went up by two. While three downvotes at once, where I only have a total of 21 posts, is strange, all within 4 minutes seems suspicious. That my profile views went up by two seems to indicate that someone used my profile to browse through other posts of mine to downvote, which = targeting. I am fairly certain all of these downvotes were by the same user. While I am fine with losing 6 reputation, I definitely think that such behavior is unacceptable and is a detriment to the site.

For reference, please see [this question on downvoting etiquette](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/serial-downvoting-and-downvoting-etiquette-in-general).

Comment: I removed “(moderator attention requested)” from the title.  If you want an attention by moderators, please flag your post for the moderator attention.

Comment: Serial downvotes are usually detected by the system and reverted within 24h, as yours are likely to be.
As for the downvoter, they are logged into the system and, if they persist in such behaviour, will eventually get a warning and some cooling-off ban time.

Comment: Thank you Dave!

Answer (score 1):

> While I am fine with losing 6 reputation, I definitely think that such behavior is unacceptable and is a detriment to the site.

Honestly speaking, I do not think that this is detrimental to the website to a noticeable extent.  Existence of a few childish users is expected and does not matter much to the website, in particular if all harm they do is to cast unreasonable down-votes.

As I wrote in an answer to the question which you linked to, there are childish people in the world, and there is nothing we can do to change this fact.  Let’s not waste too much time for them.

Comment: If left unchecked though it could become a bigger problem. The site certainly doesn't benefit from votes that don't reflect the quality of the question.

Comment: @phoenixheart6: There is no point stating the obvious fact that we will not benefit from silly behaviors of childish users.  We will not, but they are not a big deal, and there is nothing we can do about them anyway.  Assuming that these down-votes were really a retaliation, the worst thing you can do is to feed the troll and make them feel rewarded.  As you said, all harm they managed to cause you was the loss of the grand total of 6 rep points, which is nothing compared to hundreds of rep points which you have.